# VM virtual hard drive alignment

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, lvm

According to http://www.yellow-bricks.com/2010/04/08/aligning-your-vms-virtual-harddisks/ it is important to align the virtual hard drives of virtual machines for performance. I'm running virtual machines in an environment built on Debian, KVM and LVM.

What steps should be taken to get alignment right when installing a host node?

How can the alignment be checked on an already installed node?

Can the alignment be altered without re-installation? How?

Comment: Interesting. I'm going through the article but have yet to see what they mean by aligning the drives. Anyone shed light on this? (as in how do they get out of alignment in the first place)

Comment: One of the comments is saying that NT up to 7/vista(?) were just misaligned by default. Anyone know if there was a technical reason for it? Has this long been a performance issue variable and I just haven't run across it before? I'm feeling rather dim at the moment for not having heard of it before.

Comment: Also, is this an issue for all VM systems, or only those on a particular filesystem(s) or combination of filesystem(s) between guests and hosts?

Comment: @Bart, starting with Vista/2008 the partitions are aligned on 1MB by default (a common multiple of every popular block size). Before that they were commonly aligned on 31.5KB. This is an "issue" for all systems which use disks more complex than a single simple HD (with 512-byte sectors only; 31.5KB is a multiple of 512B, but isn't for just about anything else). Most newer platforms auto-align, but older ones do not hence this becoming an issue in virtualization environments where older OSes are increasingly run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the block size of your disk, or the stripe size on a raid/LVM. Misaligned partitions happen in cases where the blocks of the filesystem are not 'aligned' with the blocks on the disk (or chunks in a striped environment like storages, RAID or LVM).
So, if you have a 8k chunk size on the storage, use 8k block sizes on the host filesystem.
Also, the first partition on the disk will lose 63 kb because of the MBR, start your partition (using fdisk) on the next chunk/block boundary. Example: you have a 64k chunk on your RAID/Storage array, so start the partition on the 128th kb so you will be aligned to the 2nd chunk in your array.
Good info here: http://www.vmware.com/pdf/esx3_partition_align.pdf

**EDIT**:
To check the current alignment do a fdisk -l on the disk you are using:

```
# fdisk -lu /dev/sda
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63    97659134    48829536    7  HPFS/NTFS
```

As you can see, it is starting at 63 (right after the MBR) so its probably unaligned to the disk block size. Most people recommend you to use 128 but this value can change depending on the disk cluster size.

Unfortunately, you have to re-partition your drive to fix that, but maybe using some tool like parted you may be able to change it 'on the fly' or at least without the format.

Comment: Gparted 'on the fly' usually takes hours :-)

Answer (score 0):

see the following for a full description of the issues involved

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758814(SQL.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Found a relevant [blog post](http://thunk.org/tytso/blog/2009/02/20/aligning-filesystems-to-an-ssds-erase-block-size/)